# Database context change

Tags: mysql

Pardon my noob question but was wondering how to change the database context within mysql? I know in SQL Server, it's:

```
USE [DBName];
```

so is there an equivalent in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, if you want to change databases, you will also use `use`:

```
mysql> use DNNAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing: `use [database];` (the `;` is optional here)

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual :: 13.8.4 USE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `use` command switches databases in MySQL. The following line

```
`use [database];`
```

will switch between databases, where you substitute the actual name of your database for `[database]`, like `use db1;`.